# How to create two inputs as one form field and apply style specifically in Angular Material?

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material, angular-material2

Using Angular Material, I am building an example app with a form, which has a form field with two elements (input field and dropdown).

[image]

So, for time being, I have implemented flex styles and attributes as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <mat-label>Dessert</mat-label>
</div>
<div fxLayout="row"> 
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="80">
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="20" style="background-color: yellow;">
        <mat-select formControlName="quantity"> 
            <mat-option value="gm">Grams</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="kg">Kilos</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="mg">Milligrams</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

And if I apply same style to mat-select, then too the style is applied not correctly.

I need the bg color applied exactly to the dropdown menu.

I am learning Angular Material, so any solution provided to this is highly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set class to the mat-form-field

Stackblitz example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/style-mat-select?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="bg__yellow">
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option value="gm">Grams</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="kg">Kilos</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="mg">Milligrams</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

then in css file

```
::ng-deep mat-form-field.bg__yellow .mat-form-field-outline {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Hi @dan vid, thank you for your answer, but this too didnt work, and I should use appearance="outline" only.

Comment: Hello @bts_dev, ive edited the answer

Comment: Wow @dan vid, that worked perfectly. Lots of thanks to you! :)